# Auto width on nested list

Tags: html, css

I have a nested list like:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="" class="">
      <a href="http://site.com/wedding.html" class="">Wedding</a>

      <div class="flyoutWrapper" style="display:block;">
        <ul class="flyout fourCol">
          <li id="" class="">
     .....
          </li>
          <li></li>, etc
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want all the li's inside of class="flyout fourCol" to float next to each other.

This is what I want my dropdown to look like:

```
#nav .flyout.fourCol { width:900px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t7esz/ (this works)

```
#nav .flyout.fourCol { width:auto; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sumcA/2/ (this doesn't work!)

Comment: Instead of just linking to a working/not working JSFiddle, you need to actually explain your problem in your question, with any appropriate code snippets.

Comment: You have a remarkable skill for noticing what works and what doesn't, and stating it as well. May we note down your question too, sir?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it to expand, set the `min-width` property to a fixed value (like 900px). Keep `width` on auto.

I haven't inspected how your entire menu works, but setting that min-width on .flyout.fourCol only seems to work for the entire thing.

Comment: There's no way to make something like this completely dynamic?

Comment: @illusorydeveloper The fixed value on minimum width doesn't make it non-dynamic. It just says between which bounds it can be dynamic.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help, the width of this list is going to be changing on a regular basis as people add and remove links.

Comment: then what if you make the min-width of your entire menu something... minimal? There must be other solutions but I don't know.